# canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap on asynctask

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm getting this error when trying to retrieve an image from a url using Asynctask.
This is my asynctask:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        if (result != null && !result.isRecycled()) {
            result.recycle();
            result = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the result.recycle(), the error would be OutofMemoryError.
I'm retrieving multiple images from different url.
How can I do this? 
I'm calling the asynctask by:

```
new DownloadImageTask(imageview[i]).execute(paths.get(i));
```

Many thanks, :)

Comment: since ur images r too huge u r getting this error

Comment: Try to use any Image downloading library for achieving your task. Some  Examples are [URLImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recycle here because you still need the bitmap.  The problem is that the total amount of memory used by these bitmaps is greater than the total amount of memory available (when added to the memory used by the app already).  And because of that, the suggestion 1 person gave to use a library won't help-  it won't add memory.  Here's a few things you can do:

1)Reduce the memory used by your app.  May or may not be possible, look at a heap profiler and see if you have memory leaks.

2)Do not download all the images at once.

3)Rather than downloading them into memory, write it to a file and open each image only when actually needed.  This can be combined with an LRUCache to make sure you never use more than a fixed amount of memory.

Comment: How can I write it to a file? The only source of my images is from an external database server like mysql. and I have to download it all at once.

Comment: Instead of calling decode stream on the input stream, you write it to a FileOutputStream.  That writes it to a file.  You can then later read it from that file, rather than going back to the network.

Answer (score -2):

Use picasa library

```
 ImageView product_image = (ImageView) itemview
            .findViewById(R.id.product_image);
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(product_order_details.get(position).product_image)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.defalutimage).fit().into(product_image);
```

Comment: I'm having an error of OutofMemory when using Picasso. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add your manifest file in application tag android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: I still get the OutofMemory error. :( how can I recycle the bitmap before I put value to another ImageView? I have to load 10 large images (about 500KB) from different url.

Comment: @Min largeHeap is a hack.  If you need to use it, chances are you have architecture issues.  And even then it will only help a little bit.  That should never be your first response to a memory issue, you're just kicking the problem down the road a few weeks.